# Green's identity for arbitrary differential operators

Tags: mathematics, boundary-conditions, differential-equations, greens-functions

If we have a scalar field $\psi$ that satisfies an equation $\nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu \psi = \rho$ where $\rho$ is some known source we can use Green's identity to express it as

\begin{equation} 
\psi (x)=\int_M dV'G(x,x')\rho(x')+\int_{\partial M} dS'^{\mu} \Big[ \psi(x')\nabla_{\mu'} G(x,x')-G(x,x')\nabla_{\mu'} \psi(x')\Big] 
\end{equation}
where $G(x,x')$ is a Green's function satisfying

\begin{equation}
\nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu G(x,x')=\delta(x-x').
\end{equation}
However, I can't find how does this expression changes when the differential equation for $\psi$ is something like

\begin{equation}
\nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu \psi + V(x)\psi=\rho.
\end{equation}

I would like to know

1. What conditions does $V(x)$ need to satisfy for $\psi$ to be expressable as a Green's identity.
2. What is the form of the Green's identity in this case?

**My attempt**

Starting from the Green's identity that arises from applying the divergence theorem to the vector field $F_\mu =\phi \nabla_\mu \psi-\psi \nabla_\mu \phi $ we get

\begin{equation}
\int_M dV' \big[\phi(x')\nabla^{\mu'} \nabla_{\mu'} \psi (x')-\psi(x')\nabla^{\mu'} \nabla_{\mu'} \phi (x')\big]=\int_{\partial M} dS'n^{\mu'}\big[\phi (x')\nabla_{\mu'}\psi(x')-\psi (x')\nabla_{\mu'}\phi(x')\big]
\end{equation}

Then I note that on the left hand side I can add and substract $\phi(x')V(x')\psi(x')$ to form the differential operator $D=\nabla^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}+V(x)$. I get

\begin{equation}
\int_M dV' \big[\phi(x')D'\psi (x')-\psi(x')D' \phi (x')\big]=\int_{\partial M} dS'n^{\mu'}\big[\phi (x')\nabla_{\mu'}\psi(x')-\psi (x')\nabla_{\mu'}\phi(x')\big]
\end{equation}

Picking $\psi(x')$ as a solution to the field equation $D\psi=\rho$ and $\phi$ as the Green's function satisfying $D G(x,x')=\delta(x-x')$ returns equation exactly the same Green's identity I wrote in the beginning! I can't see if I used any assumptions on $V(x)$... is this valid for any potential?

Comment: You cannot solve a PDE when it is non-linear. Green's function uses the linearity of the PDE to add up the solutions to dirac-delta impulses at each point. Unless your potential is something like $V(\psi) = \alpha \psi$, you cannot solve it via green's function method.

Comment: You are right! Let me rewrite this question.

Comment: I think there's a subtlety here:  To make your last steps you need to be able to assume that $D'[G(x,x')] = D[G(x, x')] = \delta(x - x')$.  In the usual case we can assume that there exists such a Green's function (usually with $G(x, x') = G(|x - x'|)$) by appealing to translational and rotational symmetry.  But it's not immediately clear to me whether such logic still applies when you have a position-dependent potential $V(x)$.

Comment: (That said, this seems like it would be a problem that arises in *e.g.* solving the time-independent Schrödinger equation and I would be surprised if there isn't an answer to my objection out there somewhere)