# Existence of Green's functions with specific causality conditions

Tags: boundary-conditions, differential-equations, greens-functions

This is a follow-up to my previous question here: [Green's identity for arbitrary differential operators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/772426/greens-identity-for-arbitrary-differential-operators).

Given some scalar field theory with field $\psi$ and source $\rho$ with field equations

\begin{equation}
\Big[\nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu + V(x)\Big]\psi(x)=\rho (x)
\end{equation}

I'm interested in knowing for which potentials $V(x)$ we can find a Green's function $G(x,x')$ that satisfies $\Big[\nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu + V(x)\Big]G(x,x')=\delta(x-x')$ and

1. Is symmetric in its arguments.
2. Vanishes if $x$ and $x'$ are time-like separated.